# Fatal error: Cannot use Joomla\String\String as String because 'String' is a special class name in

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, php-7

Fatal error: Cannot use Joomla\String\String as String because 'String' is a special class name in E:\xampp\htdocs\newwinapp\libraries\vendor\joomla\registry\src\Format\Json.php on line 12

Comment: Please add the code that causes this error. This error means nothing without it.

Comment: What version of Joomla and PHP you are using?

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs if you are using a Joomla version below 3.5 on a PHP7 or higher environment.

So either install a higher version of Joomla, or revert your PHP version back to 5.6.

Comment: I actually want to update my joomla, but it is very annoying because now I can't do it automatically with the built-in update system... Any tips more than welcome.